# get city and state from zip code entered javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an existing DB that contains city, state, zip, lat, long, county:  40,000+ records.

I am able to use it with no problems.

What I'm trying to do now is when a user enters a zip code in a form, query the DB and get the associated city, state, lat, long, and county.

The script executes "ONBLUR" but nothing happens.  I verified that I'm calling the function right because I inserted a `window.alert("Test")`.

Here is the javascript:

```
function updateCityState()
   {
   {
    var zipValue = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
    if(zipValue!="")
    {
        var url = "admin/includes/zip_check.php";
        var param = "?zip=" + escape(zipValue);

        var ajax = getHTTPObject();

        ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
        ajax.send(null);
    }
}
}
 function handleAjax()
{
if (ajax.readyState == 4)
{
    citystatearr = ajax.responseText.split(",");

    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');

    city.value = citystatearr[0];
    state.value = citystatearr[1];
}
 }
```

My "zip_check.php" file looks like this.... The zip_check works when I query it manually...

```
include_once("../db.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `cities_extended` WHERE `zip`=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['zip']);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['city'].",".$row['state_code'];
```

Do I need to include something like JQuery or something else that I'm missing for this to work?  Is my syntax correct?

Comment: You have too many `{}` in there...Indenting code properly helps to catch syntax errors.

Comment: People will inform you to stop using mysql_xxxx functions in PHP as they are deprecated - use mysqli or PDO instead. Cheers and sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I used the F12 and it's telling me that "getHTTPObject" is not defined.. ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using jQuery.ajax function which does all the hard work for you! See the official API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Your jQuery code might look something like this:

```
function updateCityState()
{
    var zipValue = $('#zipcode').val();
    if(zipValue == "")
    {
        alert('enter a zip value!');
    }
    else
    {
        //process ajax request
        var zipcodeRequest = $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "admin/includes/zip_check.php",
             data: { zip:zipValue }
        });

        zipcodeRequest.done(function(data)
        {
             alert( "You have successfully found your zip code." + data );
             //do something with your data here...
             $('#city').val(data.city);
             $('#state').val(data.state);
        });

        zipcodeRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
             alert( "We could not find your zip code (" + textStatus + ")." );
        });
    }
}
```

Here are some more ajax code examples to help you figure it out:

1. http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/
2. http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/ajax/

Answer (score 2):

As @elclanrs said, you have redundant { in the `function updateCityState()`. Secondly, what kind of data type you send back from server-side? json, xml, text or html, this information very important and you have to carefully with this. By implementing AJAX methodology instead of using it via libraries such as jQuery, you have to make sure you define correctly reponse data type, handle response status and compatible with multiple browsers. The snippet code below is an example:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

Debugging on this way is not easy, in case you still want to keep this implementation, you can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp). Personally, I suggest you use jQuery to do your business.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this if you dont want to use jquery , its simple ajax but a different implementation than yours

```
function updateCityState()
{
var xmlhttp;
var zipValue = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;  
if (zipValue=="")
  {
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');

    city.value = "";
    state.value = "";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    citystatearr = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");

    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');

    city.value = citystatearr[0];
    state.value = citystatearr[1];
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/includes/zip_check.php?zip="+zipValue,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using an exact path to your php file.

```
var url = "admin/includes/zip_check.php";
```

to something like:

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/admin/includes/zip_check.php";
```

Comment: ajax requests abide to the same domain policy so including the exact path is not the solution. If the path is to be absolute to the domain http root you can simply prepend it with a forward slash /